# How to generate a chart out of retrieved data from mysql?

Tags: mysql, charts

I wanted to generate a chart from the data of two tables called `user` and `country` to show the number of users from each country.

In `user`, these are the relevant fields

```
user_id: INT , country_id: INT
```

In `country`, these are the relevant fields

```
country_id: INT , country_name: VARCHAR(45)
```

When doing a `SELECT country_id, COUNT( * ) FROM user GROUP BY country_id`, this is the result.  The `COUNT(*)` column displayed the number of users from each country which in this are 2 countries with id 1 and 2. I wanted to then generate a chart out of this result and instead of displaying the `country_id` on one axis, i wanted to retrieve the `country_name` instead. How do I do this?

```
+------+--------+--------+
| country_id | COUNT(*)  |  
+------+--------+--------+
|    1       |  100      |  
|    2       |  157      |
|    3       |  99       |
+------+--------+--------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple join should suffice

```
SELECT c.country_name, COUNT(u.user_id) as user_count
FROM country c
INNER JOIN users u ON c.country_id = u.country_id
GROUP BY c.country_name
```

For the chart, I recommend [Highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/). You'd just need to export the data as JSON, eg

```
series: [{
    data: [
        ['USA', 100],
        ['Australia', 157],
        ['New Zealand', 99]
    ]
}]
```

<kbd>[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h6g0015L/)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

try this query

```
select a.country_id, a.country_name,b.totaluser  from country a
join(
SELECT country_id, COUNT( * ) as totaluser FROM user GROUP BY country_id) b on a.country_id=b.country_id
```

Comment: Please try adding more details on how that answer could provide a solution to the problem instead of copy-pasting a code-snippet. That way, the OP (and anybody else) will be able to get a better understanding of your answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.name, COUNT(b.user_id) as From_Each_Country
FROM country a INNER JOIN Users b
INNER JOIN users u 
ON a.country_id = b.country_id
GROUP BY a.name
```

Comment: select a.hotelname, COUNT(b.roomno) As total_Room
from hotel a INNER JOIN room b
ON a.hotelno = b.hotelno
Group by a.hotelname
GO

Answer (score -1):

I don't know what you mean when you say "generate a chart", but to associate the country name with the count you might consider a join

```
SELECT country.country_name, COUNT( user.user_id ) FROM user 
join country on user.country_id=country.country_id
GROUP BY country.country_name
```

I don't have your data so I can't try it.

EDIT

Sorry, a typo...

Comment: Column 'country.country_name' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.